# Variables may not be used as commands

Tags: fish

Using fish shell, I'm writing very simple script that checks the command execution

```
#!/usr/bin/fish
command

if $status
    echo "Oops error"
else
    echo "Worked OK"
    #...
end
```

And get the error message:

> fish: Variables may not be used as commands. Instead, define a function like “function status; 0 $argv; end”. See the help section for the function command by typing “help function”.

The message looks pretty straight forward but no "defining function like..." nor "help function" helps solving the problem.

There is also a 'test' command, that sounds promising. But docs say it is to be used to check files...

How this simple thing should be done with fish shell?

Heh... And why all documentation is SO misleading?..

P.S. Please, don't write about 'and' command.

Comment: Faho already provided a good answer. I just wanted to note that I opened an enhancement issue, https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/2773, to improve the situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fish's [test](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#test) command currently works exactly like POSIX test (i.e. the one you'll find in bash or similar shells). It has a couple of operations, including "-gt", "-eq", "-lt" to check if a number is bigger, equal or less than another number, respectively.

So if you want to use test, you'll do `if test $status -eq 0` (a 0 traditionally denotes success). Otherwise, you can check the return value of a command by putting it in the if clause directly like `if command` (which will be true if the command returns 0) - that's what fish is trying to do here, which is why it complains about a variable being used in place of a command.

Comment: Thank you! I used fish help, fish site tutorials, fish site FAQ, google, stack overflow search. I wish I met the page you gave me the link to. And I wish I met this one exact phrase "Fish's test command works exactly like POSIX test" in fish help for example.

Comment: That page can be accessed via the online documentation (under "commands", also linked in the sidebar), `help test` (opens the local copy of that in a browser), `man test` (opens the man page version) or `test --help` (just prints it on the terminal).

Comment: yes, I see. What I mean is that unfortunately fish documentation is structured so that sometimes it is not obvious to find such obvious things. While just one this phrase could saved my time when I read 'help function' (is that what fish proposes me to read) or 'help test'. One short example would help with status in FAQ (everybody would test the $status it is designed for it).